# How to set Number of Lines in tty terminals

Tags: terminal, tty, display-settings, kms

I running Manjaro Linux (21.2) with KDE.  I have a large ultra-wide screen monitor with ideal resolution of 3400x1440.

KDE and Konsole appear to be running this resolution fine but when I switch to tty2(-6) terminals I am stuck with 45 Lines which is far too few for the monitor.  I expect somewhere between 60-80 would be ideal.

If I run `inxi -Fx`

In KDE (Konsole)

> Graphics:  Device-1: Intel RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
>
> Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.21.1.1 driver: loaded: modesetting resolution: 3440x1440~50Hz

In tty2

> Graphics:  Device-1: Intel RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
>
> Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.21.1.1 driver: loaded: modesetting tty: 215x45

I have checked the GRUB settings but they seem fine, I enable the GRUB menu and went into the loader. GRUB Loader displays very nicely in 3440x1400.

I also tried `resizecons -lines 60` but got this error:

> invalid columns number 0

Attempting `resizecons 215x60` gives this error:

> cannot find videomode file 215x60

I could go down the path of trying to find videomode files?

What is the correct way to do this?

I would like to work on the terminal where possible, when setup with a high resolution, the solid black background and crisp font is so much better than being in the DE.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that the terminal lines is based on the Font set, when I run `setfont` with no arguments it reprobes (if that's the right term) the terminal and changes it to a much smaller font.

Re-run `inxi -Fx` and I now get `tty: 430x90`.

I think 80 lines would be ideal so I believe I just need to find the right font and add it to `/etc/vconsole.conf` to make it persistent?

UPDATE:  Set font to `ter-p18n` and now have `tty: 344x80`. Beautiful console!